# "Seems married" vs "seems to be married" vs "seems to have got married"

Tags: meaning, difference

I've learned from my text book named [*Meaning into Words*](https://books.google.com.np/books?id=ys9DMnLiDWoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=falsebook) that “If 'seem' is followed by an adjective, we can leave **to be** and If 'seem' is followed by a noun, we can't leave **to be**.

According to the rule,
the following sentences are correct:

> 1. She/He seems to be married.
> 2. She/He seems married.

Now, I want to use **perfect infinite** in the sentence below:

> 3. She/He seems **to have got** married.

The context could be:

- A man or woman who is wearing a ring, or type of clothes which makes them "look" as if he or she is married.
- I heard a rumour that he/she got married. (Someone who I haven't met for a long time.)

Does it mean  he or she "seems" to be already married?

Are the sentences above used to express uncertainty whether someone is married or not?

Comment: This old [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79046/3463) might help.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about the rule you cite for 1 & 2, but 2 would be a commonly used construction.  At least to me, there is a difference in nuance.  "Seems to be married" is something I would associate with confirmation of evidence (I've seen the marriage certificate so she seems to be married; the paperwork appears to be in order).  "Seems married" reflects more of an internal assessment that might be based on subtle clues such as the person's behavior, manner of dress, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"To have got" isn't the perfect infinitive of "to be", that would be "to have been".

> a) "She/He seems to have got married."

At some point in the past, this person had a wedding. You could also say "seems to have got married and divorced", saying that it appears both events have happened. You can't say "seems to *be* married and divorced", that sounds contradictory.

> b) "She/He seems to have been married."

They were married, but this phrasing implies that it's no longer the case.

Comment: @fluffy, it looks like this is a pond thing.  North America = gotten, elsewhere = got.  See http://grammarist.com/usage/got-gotten/

Answer (score 0):

All your examples (1, 2 and 3) are grammatically correct. There is a difference though.

1 and 2 both use "married" as an adjective. They are suitable for your context *"A man or woman who is wearing a ring, or type of clothes which makes them "look" as if he or she is married."*

3 uses "married" as the past participle of the verb "to marry". This is suitable for your context *"I heard a rumour that he/she got married."*