# How does the following infinitive modify the sentence?

Tags: infinitives

what's the difference between the following? Is the first sentence correct? If yes in which situation both of these should be used? please help me.
1) He seemed weak.
2) He seemed to be weak.

Comment: Both sentences are correct. We can use both patterns after "seem." You'll find it in any dictionary. For example, here - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/seem

Comment: There seems to be a [nice answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/when-is-seems-to-be-used-instead-of-seems/87644) to this question already ;)