# The verb appear with a participle

Tags: participles

I want to learn how easy the verb APPEAR lends itself to the usage of itself with a participle. For example,

> His speech appeared **worrying**.
>
> What you wrote at first appeared **worrying**—but it probably must not be.

The above ones are OK, I think.
Would these work?

> Marvel appeared reading the book.
>
> Lucy appeared going somewhere.
>
> Sahar appeared going home.

Comment: In the last three sentences it should be "appeared to be"

Comment: I know that they should be that way, the question is why?

Comment: yes there is grammatical explanation for that. I will try to explain it later in an answer. In the meantime let me find out if I have any old answer for this.

Comment: Here you go: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/87989/3463

Answer (score 1):

*Appear*, like *seem*, *look*, *sound*, *feel*, can be followed by an adjectival complement, but not an *-ing* clause.

They can sometimes be followed by a noun phrase, but only in certain cases, eg *look a mess*, *seem a nice man*, but not *look a melon* or *seem a car*.

If you ask why these restrictions apply, I'm afraid that the whole of the answer is "Because that's how Modern English is".